# How to cancel a task or terminate the task execution instantly?

Tags: c#-4.0, task

I have a windows service developed in C#. On it's Start method I have a initialization such as:

```
Task _backgroundTask = null;

CancellationTokenSource _backgroundCancellationSource = null;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

......

_backgroundCancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

CancellationToken token = backgroundCancellationSource.Token;

_backgroundTask = new Task(() => BackgroundFoldersProcessing(token), token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

.......
}
```

Now the method BackgroundFoldersProcessing looks like this:

```
void BackgroundFoldersProcessing(CancellationToken token)
{

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {                        
                        return;
                    }

                    DoSomeWork()
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    .........
                }
            }
}
```

Now, the Stop method is as follows:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
.................

_backgroundCancellationSource.Cancel();
_backgroundTask.Wait();

_backgroundCancellationSource.Dispose();
_backgroundTask.Dispose();

_backgroundTask = null;
_backgroundCancellationSource = null;

.................
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to stop the service in a middle of processing, the Wait method of _backgroundTask would not stop the service until and unless the DoSomeWork() method inside the BackgroundFoldersProcessing gets completed, the Windows Service would not stop.

Is there any way, though which I can stop the service and the execution of _backgroundTask would be terminated, even though the DoSomeWork() method gets completed/executed or not? I have also tried token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() in BackgroundFoldersProcessing method, but that also did not worked. I want that whenever I try to Stop the service from Service Control Manager (SCM), the service should be stopped immediately and the __backgroundTask should stop executing the BackgroundFoldersProcessing method and be terminated as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is DoSomeWork() simply taking too long? You are waiting for it to finish. You might want to try Wait(TimeSpan) overload and set it to three seconds.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Yes, the DoSomeWork() takes quite a long time depending upon the input. Actually, I am giving Package (.zip) file as an input. So, processing a package may take few seconds to several minutes, depending upon the contents of a package. And, actually I tried the Wait(TimeSpan) as well as the Wait(int milliSeconds), and other overloaded Wait method. And yes, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use ThreadAbortException:

defining the thread:

```
ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(BackgroundFoldersProcessing);
Thread thread_ = new Thread(threadDelegate);
thread_.Start();
```

Add catch to BackgroundFoldersProcessing

```
catch (ThreadAbortException e)
{
     return;
}
```

and when you want to shut it down use:

```
thread_.Abort();
thread_.Join();
```

Then when **Abort()** will be called ThreadAbortException will be thrown.

Comment: That might be a good approach, and it might work well in a single-threaded environment, but I am concerned about Thread-safety in multi-threaded environment. Say I move the code into a class say Work. In the Work class I may develop a method Start() and Stop() and call that method in OnStart and OnStop of Windows Service. Now, if I create and use multiple instance of Work class, then would the approach suggested by you would be thread-safe and would all the threads running would execute asynchronously?